# Names of actual software which use the LDA classifier

Tags: classification, predictive-models, software, application

I read generic claims online and in papers that the Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) classifier is widely used for many applications including: face recognition, speech recognition, medical diagnosis, etc... Many research papers also propagate these claims with no mention of actual systems.

But this suggests that these are just potential applications, while I need concrete examples. Does anybody know the names of actual systems which are based on LDA?

Comment: R does have functions for dealing with LDA.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using LDA for dimensionality reduction and classification based on data with assigned classes, you have plenty of options, including:

- Scikit-Learn in python
- Mass in R
- fitcdiscr in MATLAB

In practice, the math behind LDA is quite simple, so I'd recommend doing some of it by hand to make sure your method makes sense.